# Looping through external JSON file

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file containing two different holiday resorts. I would like to compare the values within two dropdown menus with the two values in the JSON file.

For example, if the `destination` dropdown menu has the value "Caribbean" selected and the `comfortLevel`dropdown has the value "4" selected, then I would like to search through the external JSON file, find the resort matching those descriptions, and display all the information for those matching resorts.

HTML:

```
        <div class="searchDestination">
            <br>
            <label><b>Select your destination: &nbsp;</b></label>
            <select id="destination">
                <option value="0">Please Select:</option>
                <option value="europe">Europe</option>
                <option value="africa">Africa</option>
                <option value="carribian">The Carribian</option>
                <option value="asia">Asia</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="searchComfortLevel">
        <br>
        <label><b>Select your Comfort Level: &nbsp;</b></label>
        <select id="comfortLevel">
            <option value="0">Please Select:</option>
            <option value="3">Three Star</option>
            <option value="4">Four Star</option>
            <option value="5">Five Star</option>>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="buttons">
        <button id="reset" class="button-error pure-button" style="color:white">Reset</button> 
        <button id="search" class="button-success pure-button" style="margin-left:5px; color:white">Search</button>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "#search" ).click(function() {
    var destination = $('option:selected', "#destination").attr('value');
    var comfortLevel = $('option:selected', "#comfortLevel").attr('value');
    $.getJSON('resort.json', function (data) {
        $.each(resorts, function(i, v) {
            if (v.destination == "Carribian") {
                alert(v.destination);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Resort.json

```
{ 
    "resort": [
        {
            "id":"resort1",
            "destination":"Carribean",
            "name":"Les Boucaniers",
            "location":"Martinique",
            "comfortLevel": "4",
            "activities":["water skiing", "tennis", "scuba diving", "kitesurf", "spa"],
            "price":1254,
            "startDate":"2016-01-01",
            "endDate":"2016-12-31",
            "short_description":"The resort of Les Boucaniers is located on the laid-back beach-covered south coast of the island, and is perfectly placed for Martinique holidays that are both relaxing and awe-inspiring.",
            "picture":"images/resort1pic1small.jpg",
            "long_description":"A divers' paradise in the Baie du Marin, a legendary spot.<br>Its bungalows are discreetly lodged in a tropical garden beside the white sand beach in superb Marin Bay. A magical site where you can enjoy a taste of everything, alone or with family or friends. Try water sports and the magnificent Club Med Spa*. You'll be enchanted by the exotic flavours of the local cuisine and the joyful spirit of the Caribbean.",
            "url":"resorts/resort1.html"
        },
        {
            "id":"resort2",
            "destination":"Indian Ocean",
            "name":"La Plantation d'Albion",
            "location":"Mauritius",
            "comfortLevel": "5",
            "activities":["kids club","golf", "scuba diving", "flying trapeze", "tennis", "sailing", "spa"],
            "price":2062,
            "startDate":"2016-01-01",
            "endDate":"2016-12-31",
            "short_description":"Beautifully located in one of the last remote creeks on the island, La Plantation d'Albion Club Med welcomes the most demanding of guests into a world of supreme refinement.",
            "picture":"images/resort2pic1small.jpg",
            "long_description":"In a remote beauty spot, savour the luxury of Mauritian lifestyle. <br> The idyllic natural setting is enhanced by the sublime decor designed by Marc Hertrich and Nicolas Adnet, and the Resort's top-end comfort is perfectly reflected in its beautifully spacious rooms. The exceptional CINQ MONDES Spa* and luxurious overflow pool add an ideally Zen touch.<br> The Resort is entirely devoted to fulfilling its guests' desires and offers discreet, personal service in its swimming areas, bars and 'Table Gourmet' restaurants.",
            "url":"resorts/resort2.html"
        }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through the wrong data:

```
$( "#search" ).click(function() {
    var destination = $('option:selected', "#destination").attr('value');
    var comfortLevel = $('option:selected', "#comfortLevel").attr('value');

    $.getJSON('resort.json', function (data) {
        $.each(data.resort, function(i, v) { // <-- line changed
            if (v.destination == "Caribbean") { // <-- fixed typo
                alert(v.destination);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Note:** Are you sure the return JSON says "resort" not "resorts"? If that's the case then update the line accordingly.

Comment: SamG this is the better answer.

Comment: @technophobia I am getting the following errors in Firefox: `not well-formed resort.json:1:1` and `TypeError: a is undefined jquery.min.js:2:2816`

Comment: Perhaps your `data` is not JSON - can you check that the returned data is valid json with a root level attribute called "resort"?

Comment: @technophobia How do I do that?

Comment: I just noticed you also have a typo: "Carribian" should be spelled "Caribbean"

Comment: @technophobia I have made all your corrections and still no luck - I am still getting `not well-formed resort.json:1:1` in Firefox. Have you attempted it yourself?

Comment: @SamG Are you running your site via a server or through the file system? If you're running through the file system then I believe this will not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#search" ).click(function() {
    var destination = $('option:selected', "#destination").attr('value');
    var comfortLevel = $('option:selected', "#comfortLevel").attr('value');
    $.getJSON('resort.json', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            $.each(v, function(i, resort) {
                if (resort.destination == "Carribian") {
                    alert(v.destination);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```